# Dynamic define_method throwing error in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, metaprogramming, rspec2

I am pretty sure I am missing a basic mistake here, so I am hoping another set of eyes might help. I am using Rails 3, Ruby 1.9.2 and Rspec 2.

I would like to define dynamic class methods on a model so that I can return base roles for an assignable object (such as account) as they are added to the system. For example:

```
BaseRole.creator_for_account
```

Everything works fine via the console:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > BaseRole.respond_to?(:creator_for_account)
 => true
```

but when I run my specs for any of class methods, I get a `NoMethodError` wherever I call the method in the spec. I am assuming that something about how I am dynamically declaring the methods is not jiving with RSpec but I cannot seem to figure out why.

The lib dir is autoloaded path and the methods return true for respond_to?.

```
# /lib/assignable_base_role.rb
module AssignableBaseRole
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    BaseRole.all.each do |base_role|
      role_type = RoleType.find(base_role.role_type_id)
      assignable_name = base_role.assignable_type.downcase
      method = "#{role_type.name}_for_#{assignable_name}"

      define_method(method) do
        self.where(:role_type_id => role_type.id,
                :assignable_type => assignable_name).first
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

Then include the Module in BaseRole

```
# /models/base_role.rb
class BaseRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AssignableBaseRole

  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :role_type

  ......
  ......

end
```

Then in my spec:

```
  it "adds correct authority for creator role" do
    create_assignment 
    base_role = BaseRole.creator_for_account # <== NoMethodError here
    user1 = Factory.create(:user)
    account.users << user1
    user1.roles_for_assignable(account).should include(base_role.role)
  end
```

Comment: If you remove the module, is it still an issue?  I'm getting this as well with define_method on a class file, only with rspec within guard.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have another class in your project or specs with the same name, but doesn't have the dynamic methods added? I had the exact same problem as you, and renaming one of the classes fixed it.

My guess is the other class is getting loaded first

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are defining these methods based on values in the database:

```
BaseRole.all.each do |base_role|
.....
```

Could it be that "creator" doesn't exist in the test database as a role type, or "account" doesn't exist as assignable_type?

Presumably you are testing this in the console for development, not test, so the data could be mismatched. Might need to set up the data in a before hook.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did verify that the test data is present. I am loading the data via the database and am using the console in development, mostly to see if would define the methods, given the weirdness in RSpec. But you might be on to something with the before book and/or preloading the data somehow. It could be something different in how everything is loaded and / or when I am playing with the console vs the test environment.

Comment: Cool. interested to hear what you find out.